# How to use NOT IN with LIKE in a search function?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, where-clause

I have a form in which I bring product names. I exclude the ones that are in another table.

```
SELECT ID_Produto, NomeProduto 
FROM tbl_produtos 
where ID_Produto Not IN (Select ID_Produto from tbl_produtos_parceiros)
order by NomeProduto
```

Results are as expected.

In the same form I have a search function. I tried the same condition, `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_produtos 
WHERE  id_produto LIKE '%ALH%' 
        OR nomeproduto LIKE '%ALH%' 
        OR responsavel LIKE '%ALH%' 
        OR precovenda LIKE '%ALH%' 
           AND id_produto NOT IN (SELECT id_produto 
                                  FROM   tbl_produtos_parceiros);
```

Still brings the product "Alho", which is on the tbl_produtos_parceiros.

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses around the `OR`ed conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_produtos 
WHERE  
    (
           id_produto  LIKE '%ALH%' 
        OR nomeproduto LIKE '%ALH%' 
        OR responsavel LIKE '%ALH%' 
        OR precovenda  LIKE '%ALH%' 
    )
    AND id_produto NOT IN (SELECT id_produto FROM tbl_produtos_parceiros);
```

Why you need this is because `OR` has lower logical precedence than `AND`. Without the parentheses, your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_produtos 
WHERE  
       id_produto  LIKE '%ALH%' 
    OR nomeproduto LIKE '%ALH%' 
    OR responsavel LIKE '%ALH%' 
    OR (
        precovenda  LIKE '%ALH%' 
        AND id_produto NOT IN (SELECT id_produto FROM tbl_produtos_parceiros)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is MS Access, you need to fix your wildcards and string delimiters as well as fix the syntax.  I would also recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM tbl_produtos as p
WHERE (id_produto LIKE "*ALH*" OR
       nomeproduto LIKE "*ALH*" OR
       responsavel LIKE "*ALH*" OR
       precovenda LIKE "*ALH*" 
      ) AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_produtos_parceiros as pp
                  WHERE pp.id_produto = p.id_produto
                 );
```